# block current window for n seconds with JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js

I am developping a web app using backboneJs and nodeJS, I want to oblige the user to not close this current window for 10 seconds, after 10 seconds he can do whatever he likes. Is it possible with JS?

Comment: You want to hide the close button from browser? Nah.. Not possible.

Comment: You can display a message that must be clicked (window.onbeforeunload), thankfully thats the closest you can get.

Comment: So lets say, for example you're playing an adult video on your site and force the user to not close his browser? Or maybe something worse?Thankfully it's not possible.

Comment: actually I am sending SMS then ACKin my app, I want to block the window so in case I have a big number SMS and Ack to send, the window is blocked until it is finished. So unfortuntely it is not possible, because i will have to run a script every time

Answer (score 1):

The window settings are controlled by your browser (Chrome/Firefox/Safari etc.). So anything that lies beyond what appears on the website screen is not in our control.

Incase you want to ensure the user reads a particular message for a given timestamp, I suggest using `popovers` or a custom landing page should be of good use.